# ¿En qué momento se construye una copia del objeto en este código? ¿Antes o después de la función?

Tags: c++

Con el siguiente código:

```
class C { ... } c1;
C func(C& ref) 
{    
// función que devuelve un objeto
  ...
  return ref;
}
...
{
  ...
  c2 = func(c1);
}
```

Cuando una función devuelve un objeto es otra alternativa de cuando se usa el constructor de copia, pero ¿alguien me podría explicar exactamente cuando se crea dicha copia?

Porque por un lado, la función esa que he puesto crea una referencia del objeto `c1`. Entonces trabaja con él, y justo cuando ocurre `return ref;` ¿es cuando se llama al constructor de copia para copiar `ref`? O lo hace cuando sale de la función `func` y ocurre `func(c1);` y luego de esa copia temporal ya se asigna con el `operador=()` a `c2`?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> C func(C& ref) 
> {    
> // función que devuelve un objeto
>   ...
>   return ref;
> }
> ```
>
> La función esa que he puesto crea una referencia.

No. La función `func` recibe una referencia a un objeto que existe en otro contexto, ahí no hay ninguna creación de objeto.

> Justo cuando ocurre `return ref`; ¿es cuando se llama al constructor de copia para copiar `ref`?

Correcto, el retorno de `func` es `C`, en otras palabras "*La función `func` devuelve una **instancia** de tipo `C`*"; la única manera de devolver una instancia es creándola.

#### Probando el código.

Si añadimos unos chivatos al objeto `C` podremos ver su comportamiento:

```
#include <iostream>

#define chivato std::cout << this << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct C
{
    C() { chivato; }
    C(const C &) { chivato; }
    ~C() { chivato; }
} c1;

C func(C& ref) 
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " recibe " << &ref << '\n';
    return ref;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Empieza main\n";
    auto c2 = func(c1);
    std::cout << "main va a acabarse\n";
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [produce la siguiente salida](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Sa97A1L0VPIC0s7J):

> ```
> 0x6013d1 C::C()
> Empieza main
> C func(C&) recibe 0x6013d1
> 0x7ffec496789f C::C(const C&)
> main va a acabarse
> 0x7ffec496789f C::~C()
> 0x6013d1 C::~C()
> ```

1. El primer constructor (del objeto `0x6013d1`) se corresponde con la instancia `c1` en espacio global; al alojarse en espacio global se crea antes de la llamada a `main` (y posiblemente por eso tenga otro tipo de dirección de memoria, pero eso es dependiente de implementación).
2. Se llama a la función `main`.
3. `c1` es pasado a `func` sin provocar ninguna copia de objeto (de ser así, se habría visto el chivato del constructor de copia `C::C(const C&)` antes de entrar en `func`).
4. Se crea un nuevo objeto (`0x7ffec496789f`) dentro de `func` copiando `c1` y volvemos a `main` almacenando el objeto anteriormente creado en `c2`.
5. Se muestra el último chivato de `main`.
6. Se destruye `c2` (`0x7ffec496789f`) por salir del ámbito de `main`.
7. Se destruye `c1` (`0x6013d1`) porque después de `main` se libera la memoria automática.

#### Optimización del Valor de Retorno (OVR).

Los compiladores de C++ pueden evitar copiar los objetos devueltos en una función si deducen que el programa se comportará igual construyendo el objeto directamente fuera de la función. Vamos a cambiar el código de prueba para demostrarlo:

```
#include <iostream>

#define chivato std::cout << this << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct C
{
    C() { chivato; }
    C(const C &) { chivato; }
    ~C() { chivato; }
}; // No creamos instancia en la definición de 'C'.

C func() // 'func' no recibe referencia
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    C temp;      // Creamos un objeto 'C' temporal.
    return temp; // Devolvemos el temporal creado dentro de 'func'.
}

C c1 = func(); // Creamos un objeto 'C' en espacio global mediante 'func'.

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Empieza main\n";
    auto c2 = func();
    std::cout << "main va a acabarse\n";
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [produce la siguiente salida](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rWlfmnladAI4PrmQ):

> ```
> C func()
> 0x6013d1 C::C()
> Empieza main
> C func()
> 0x7ffc46cb975f C::C()
> main va a acabarse
> 0x7ffc46cb975f C::~C()
> 0x6013d1 C::~C()
> ```

1. Se llama a `func` antes que `main` para inicializar el objeto `c1`.
2. Se construye `c1` (`0x6013d1`) en el espacio global.
3. Se llama a la función `main`.
4. Se llama a `func` desde `main` para inicializar el objeto `c2`.
5. Se construye `c2` (`0x7ffc46cb975f`) en el ámbito de `main`.
6. Se muestra el último chivato de `main`.
7. Se destruye `c2` (0x7ffc46cb975f) por salir del ámbito de `main`.
8. Se destruye `c1` (0x6013d1) porque después de `main` se libera la memoria automática.

Llama la atención que el constructor de copia de `C` no se ha llamado ni una sola vez pese a que `func` devuelve instancias de `C`. Esto es porque el compilador ha aplicado [OVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) al detectar que el retorno de `func` podía ser construido directamente en el punto de llamada en lugar de crear el objeto dentro y copiarlo fuera.

En versiones anteriores a C++17 se puede desactivar la OVR configurando adecuadamente el compilador, pero a partir de C++17 se garantiza la OVR a nivel de [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 15.8.3 Omisión de copia/movimiento
>
> 1. **Cuando se dan ciertos criterios, se permite a una implementación omitir la construcción mediante copia/movimiento de un objeto**, incluso cuando el constructor seleccionado para la operación de copia/movimiento y/o el destructor de dicho objeto tenga efectos secundarios. En estos casos, **la implementación trata el objeto origen y el objeto destino de la operación de copia/movimiento omitida como dos maneras diferentes de referirse al mismo objeto**. [...] Esta omisión de las operaciones de copia/movimiento, llamada *omisión de copia*, se permite en las siguientes circunstancias (que pueden ser combinadas para eliminar múltiples copias):
>
>    1. **En una instrucción `return` en una función con tipo de retorno objeto, cuando la expresión de retorno es el nombre de un objeto automático no-volátil** (excepto los parámetros de la función [...]) con el mismo tipo (ignorando las cualificaciones cv) que el tipo de retorno de la función, **la operación de copia/movimiento puede ser omitida construyendo el objeto automático directamente en el objeto que devolverá la función**.